# eclipse c++ cannot run

Tags: eclipse, build

Eclipse has been acting weird since installation. I've installed mingw and cygwin, but it only

works with executable projects. when i try creating the default gnu autotools or makefile

projects, even though the mingw gcc is selected, they cannot run. by that i mean, when hitting

build, the build window pops out and say build all and invoking command, but when i run , the

"Launch Failed. Binary not found" dialogue would appear

I would really appreciate it if you guys can help me.